# How to find following who is also following me with Gremlin

Tags: groovy, gremlin

What's the most direct way to find all nodes that share a bidirectional edge with a specific node using Gremlin? For example, I want to find all users that I follow who also follow me. If I follow them and they follow me, then we must be friends. Otherwise the relationship is one way.

The answer might be too obvious for me to see. I've come up with this, but it seems more complicated than necessary:

```
me=g.v(_id); me.out('follows').as("following").out('follows').filter{it == me}.back("following")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

```
me.out('follows').out('follows').retain([me]).back(2)
```

This says:

1. Start with me.
2. Figure out who I follow.
3. Figure out who they follow.
4. Kill paths that don't lead back to me.
5. Go back to those people that follow me. (which are also the people that I follow).